# adFormResponses Returns "Not enough permissions to access: GET-account /adFormResponses"

Tags: linkedin-api

I understand that I need to have "`rw_ads`" permission to access the "`adFormResponses`" end point.

However even though I have been granted that level of permission, I am still getting the

> Not enough permissions to access: GET-account /adFormResponses

error.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Requests to `adFormResponses` requires the `r_ads_leadgen_automation` permission scope as well.

Comment: okay, How do you request additional permissions scope then in the API Console? Do I have to make a new app or is there a form I can fill out?